# graph api likes in merged pages

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-page

I have a page from several languages, merged into one. my problem is that I have an app in this page and I need to check if the user is fan of that page, but with this king of pages, merged pages, api allways return empty data in me/likes/XXXX graph api call.
How can I get this working with this kind of pages?
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

you can use FQL to check, e.g. your fan page id is 1234, then you can use

```
SELECT page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid=me() AND page_id>1233  AND page_id<1235
```

if user liked, it will return one record

NOTE: DO NOT USE

```
SELECT page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid=me() AND page_id=1234
```

it cannot work!

Comment: Why is the second example not working? Can you explain it a little bit more for the asker?

Comment: It is a facebook bug, for merged fanpage, using pages.isFan and FQL page_id=1234 cannot work
So, before facebook fix pages.isFan bug, using FQL is the possble workaround

Comment: Please add this explanation to your answer :)